# I am trying to show sum of OrderQty for same type of Product and total price. But Showing this error in Aggregate Function

Tags: c#, sql-server-2012

```
Select pl.ProductName AS 'Product Name', 
    Sum(OrderQty), 
    (od.OrderQty * pl.Price) as 'Total Amount'
From ProductList pl 
Inner Join OrderDetails od ON pl.ProductID = od.ProductId
Group By pl.ProductName
```

But showing this error message:

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 2 Column 'OrderDetails.OrderQty' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either  an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
>
> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 2 Column 'ProductList.Price' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an  aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not summing the total:

```
Select  pl.ProductName AS 'Product Name', 
        SUM(OrderQty), 
        SUM(od.OrderQty * pl.Price) as 'Total Amount'
From ProductList pl 
Inner Join OrderDetails od ON pl.ProductID = od.ProductId
Group By pl.ProductName
```